# Gimp batch process for 'tiling' images

Tags: gimp, automation, batch-processing

I have a directory containing several images size 640*480px and I'd like an automated procedure using Gimp to pick these up and 'tile' the images beside each other with no overlap, to make a new large image a bit like a proof sheet.  For example, the output image could be four source images wide by ten deep, for a 2560*4800 resulting image.

Answer (score 3):

Why use Gimp for this. Use ImageMagick's [`montage` command](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#montage).

Answer (score 2):

## Use ImageMagick instead

Whenever you need to do a bulk image operation and you are reaching for GIMP *stop and try ImageMagick first*. 99% of the time, it's the right tool for the job.

In this case, the Imagemagick [`montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) command is just what you need.

```
montage -geometry +0+0 *.png montage.png
```

This will result in a tile sheet named "montage.png" that contains all PNG files in the current directly, with no border and no resizing. Imagemagick will count the number of images and determine the appropriate number of tiles per row (which you can manually override with the `-tile` argument).

The [`montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) command has lots of options to tweak if you need something more specific.

## "But I asked for GIMP..."

If you are hellbent on doing this in GIMP, I'm not sure how. A quick google search reveals lots of plugins and techniques for manipulating a tileset (like you'd see in an old-but-still-awesome 8-bit RPG), but I didn't find an easy way to stitch together a bunch of images except doing it by hand.